# what does it mean define macro function as (0)?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I see in some source code this kind of definition

```
#define somemacro(a,b,c) (0)
```

And I see in the same source code:

```
#define anothermacro(a,b,c) (1)
```

Can any body explain this kind of macro definition? what is the purpose of such definition?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the error. Macros define literal replacements.

Comment: If the code you posted causes a segmentation fault then there is something wrong with your compiler

Comment: Instead of calling a function, the macro expands to a constant.  I don't see how it could cause a crash (segmentation fault) though — the program should simply run and exit with status zero (if you use C99 or above; with an indeterminate value if you use C90).

Comment: to all, I made mistake the program does not crash. But what is the purpose of such definition?

Comment: In some condition, the platform may not support the function. It should be conditional compile command there, like `#if`. If it is not that way, I can not find out why need to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Usually non-used parameters of a function like macro occurs in the following situation:

```
#ifdef A_IS_GREAT_ALWAYS
  #define anothermacro(a,b,c) (1)
#else
  #define anothermacro(a,b,c) ((a)>(b)+(c))
#endif
```

Without parameters it would break the build in the following kind of places, when A_IS_GREAT_ALWAYS is not defined.

```
...
if (anothermacro(foo, bar, baz))
...
```

The precompiler translates the example code to:

```
  if ((1))
```

or

```
  if (((foo)>(bar)+(baz)))
```

depending is the A_IS_GREAT_ALWAYS defined or not.